# Which iOS devices don't support ASTC texture compression?

Tags: ios, compression, metal, astc

iPad 3 is definitely not. CPU decompression lags like hell, I want to know approximately how many user encounters this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASTC support was introduced with iOS_GPUFamily2_v1, which corresponded with the release of the A8 processor (iPhone 6, iPad mini 4). The first "big" iPad with ASTC support was iPad Air 2.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it is a whole lot people. :( http://blakespot.com/ios_device_specifications_grid.html

Answer (score 3):

Made an excerpt for later reference. 
Device models with processors.

**iPhone** (Samsung S5L8900) 
**iPod touch** (Samsung S5L8900) 
**iPhone 3G** (Samsung S5L8720) 
**iPod touch 2G** (Samsung S5L8720) 
**iPhone 3GS** (Samsung S5PC100) 
**iPod touch 3G** (Samsung S5PC100) 
**iPad** (Apple A4) 
**iPhone 4** (Apple A4) 
**iPod touch 4G** (Apple A4) 
**Apple TV 2G** (Apple A4) 
**iPad 2** (Apple A5) 
**iPhone 4S** (Apple A5) 
**iPad 3G** (Apple A5X) 
**Apple TV 3G** (Apple A5) 
**iPhone 5** (Apple A6) 
**iPod touch 5G** (Apple A5) 
**iPad 4G** (Apple A6X) 
**iPad mini** (Apple A5) 
**iPhone 5c** (Apple A6) 
**iPhone 5s** (Apple A7) 
**iPad Air** (Apple A7) 
**iPad mini 2** (Apple A7)